# The property 'uid' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.')

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have three error:

1. Error: The getter 'user' isn't defined for the type 'User'. Try importing the library that defines 'user', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'user'
2. Error: The getter 'user' isn't defined for the type 'User'. Try importing the library that defines 'user', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'user'
3. Error: The property 'uid' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')

```
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

    class _AuthService {
      final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
      final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

      //giriş yap
      Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {
        var user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);
        return User.user;
      }

      //çıkış yap
      signOut() async {
        return await _auth.signOut();
      }

      //kayıt ol
      Future<User> createPerson(String name, String lastname,
          String telephoneNumber, String email, String password) async {
        var user = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password);

        await _firestore.collection('Person').doc(user.user.uid).set({
          'name': name,
          'lastname': lastname,
          'telephone': telephoneNumber,
          'email': email,
        });

        return User.user;
      }
```

Comment: I mean the error kinda speaks for itself. You're calling .user on user, which is a non-existing property. the last one also does, you're calling .uid on a nullable property, so you might wanna consider using user?.uid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line here looks wrong:

```
Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  var user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  return User.user;
}
```

First off, the `User` in `User.user` is a class. More likely you want to refer to the `user` **variable** that you declared in the line above, so: `return user.user`.

So this has a better chance:

```
Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  var user = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  return user.user;
}
```

And since I know we'll get confused about `user.user`, I prefer giving the variable a different name:

```
Future<User> signIn(String email, String password) async {
  var credentials = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, password: password);
  return credentials.user;
}
```

It looks like you have the same problem in `createPerson`, so you'll have to change it there too.